# Deserializing a complex JSON (several nested elements) with Gson

Tags: android, json, serialization, gson

I am trying to deserialize a JSON object (which comes from an API) into their respective Java Objects. I am using the gson library (for Android). The thing is that I have been trying for several days and tested many several options with no luck so I would really appreciate a little help on this one.

*JSONs retrieved. All the JSONs I receive from the API follow the following structure:

```
{
"status_code": 200,
"status_message": "Here the status message",
"result": {
    "success": true,
    "internalStatusCall": 1,
    "response": 
            /* Can be a JSON object or a JSON array of objects    */   
    }
}
```

Since the structure of all of JSONs received would be similar, I would like to take advantage of that and extend the Objects to map from JSON.

I would think on something like:

```
public class TABaseObject {

@SerializedName("status_code")
protected int status_code;

@SerializedName("status_message")
protected String status_message;

protected String type;

public TABaseObject(int status_code, String status_message, String type) {
    this.status_code = status_code;
    this.status_message = status_message;
    this.type = type;
}
}
```

Extending from this object, the inner object would be:

```
public class TAResultObject extends TABaseObject{

@SerializedName("exito")
protected boolean exito;

@SerializedName("codigoEstado")
protected int codigoEstado;

public TAResultObject(int status_code, String status_message, boolean exito, int codigoEstado) {
    super(status_code, status_message, "resultado");
    this.exito = exito;
    this.codigoEstado = codigoEstado;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + " ////// " + "TAResultObject{" +
            "exito=" + exito +
            ", codigoEstado=" + codigoEstado +
            '}';
}
```

and from this other object, I would extend TAResultObject to the correspondent Object.

I have tried several deserializing approaches (TypeAdapterFactory, RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory, etc...) with no luck.

Is there any strategie to be able to deserialize the mentioned JSON. I really would appreciate any help on this one.

Comment: It's hard to map the provided JSON and the mappings in head. Did you probably miss something else to add?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution with Response class,

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class TAObject {

        @SerializedName("status_code")
        Integer status_code ;

        @SerializedName("status_message")
        String status_message ;

        @SerializedName("result")
        Result result ; 

        public class Result {

            @SerializedName("success")
            Boolean success ;

            @SerializedName("internalStatusCall")
            Integer internalStatusCall ;

            @SerializedName("response")
            List<Map> response ;

        }
    }
```

Use this class along with a Custom TypeAdapter for Gson .Then it will work for both List and Object response .

ArrayAdapter class

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


 class ArrayAdapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<List<T>> {

    private Class<T> adapterclass;

    public ArrayAdapter(Class<T> adapterclass) {
        this.adapterclass = adapterclass;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {

        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ArrayAdapterFactory()).create();

        final JsonToken token = reader.peek();
        System.out.println(token);
        // Handling of Scenario 2( Check JavaDoc for the class) :
        if (token == JsonToken.STRING || token == JsonToken.NUMBER ||
                token == JsonToken.BOOLEAN) {
            T inning = (T) gson.fromJson(reader, adapterclass);
            list.add(inning);
        } else if (token == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {
            // Handling of Scenario 1(Check JavaDoc for the class) :
            T inning = (T) gson.fromJson(reader, adapterclass);
            list.add(inning);
        } else if (token == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
            reader.beginArray();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                T inning = (T) gson.fromJson(reader, adapterclass);
                list.add(inning);
            }
            reader.endArray();
        }

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter writer, List<T> value) throws IOException {

    }


}
```

ArrayAdapterFactory class

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type)
    {

        TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = null;
        try {
            if (type.getRawType() == List.class || type.getRawType() == ArrayList.class) {

                typeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(
                        (Class) ((ParameterizedType) type.getType())
                                .getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return typeAdapter;

    }

}
```

And register the adapter factory like this,

```
Gson gson  = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ArrayAdapterFactory()).create();
```